# Accessing a Cloud Run service from another project

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

Can I access the CloudRun api from a different project using a ServiceAccount from that project ?

I have a Project A, in which a CloudRun service (ServiceA) is hosted.
I have another Project B, from which I need to call ServiceA using a service account (SvcAcccountB).

But every time I try to make the call to ServiceA using SvcAccountB it fails with a 403. There is no firewall issue as I can see in the logs for ServiceA that call is getting rejected.
I have given the "CloudRun Invoker" permissions to SvcAccountB.

If I have service account (svcAccountA) in Project A, then the call to ServiceA works fine.

What else am I missing so that svcAccountB can call ServiceA?

Comment: Yes, you can assign CloudRun Invoker to any valid Google account email. I do this all the time. Your question does not show how you are calling Cloud Run. Make sure that you are using an Identity Token and not an Access Token.

Comment: That's the problem, wrong auth.

Comment: Can you explain what's the full metadata `/identity` URL you're calling? i.e. what's the `?audience=` value etc? I suspect you have an issue there. If `?audience=` is not valid, you will still get a token but it won't work.

Comment: I got this to work. Posted the details as an answer. John Hanley's site helped https://www.jhanley.com

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 steps you need to post to CloudRun Service using a service account:-

1. Get a JWT Token using your service account json file
   Here's a sample Claims:-

   `Iat: now,
       // expires after 'expiraryLength' seconds.
       Exp: now + expiryLength,
       // Iss must match 'issuer' in the security configuration in your
       // swagger spec (e.g. service account email). It can be any string.
       Iss: saEmail,
       // Aud must be either your Endpoints service name, or match the value
       // specified as the 'x-google-audience' in the OpenAPI document.
       Aud: "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token",
       // Sub and Email should match the service account's email address.
       Sub:           saEmail,
       PrivateClaims: map[string]interface{}{"target_audience": audience},`

   where the audience is the url of your CloudRun service.
2. Pass this JWT token to get the Access token
   Here's more details : https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount
3. Then send the Access token to your CloudRun service.